# Accessing array object property in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Given the following array in `vue.js`:

```
packageMaps: Object
    packageMap_0: Object
        Id: 16
        PackageType: "flag_list"
        ProductCode: "F-BannerBase"
    packageMap_1: Object
        Id: 82
        PackageType: "flag_list"
        ProductCode: "F-TeardropBanner"
    ....
....
```

...and given the value `F-TeardropBanner`, how can I access the given array and return the relevant `PackageType`?

```
populatePackageList(productCode) {
  let packageList = [];
  let packageType = '';
  for(let key in this.packageMaps.ProductCode) {
      if(productCode === this.packageMaps[key];
      // not sure what to do here or if I am on the right track
  }
  this.formData.packageList = Object.assign({}, this.formData.packageList, packageList);
},
```

[image: Array as it appears in vue.js]

Comment: Can you share the proper data `array`?

Comment: I only have the front end data -the JSON is interpreted by vue.js as represented above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your response data is BIG in size, convert that response data to another object with `(key,value)` as {`product Id` : `packageMap_x_object`}, like below, thus retrieval will be fast

```
let newPackageMaps = {
  "F-BannerBase": packageMap_0_Object
  "F-TeardropBanner":packageMap_1_Object
   ..........
   ..........
} 

populatePackageList(productCode) {
   //---------- more code----------------
  let packageMapItem = newPackageMaps[productCode]? 
      newPackageMaps[productCode]:null;
  //---------- more code ----------
}
```

OR in simple you can use a for..in loop,

```
for (let packageMap in this.packageMaps) {
  if(packageMap.ProductCode == input_ProductCode ){
       // more code
       break;
   }
}
```