# Passing an array object property from Laravel in Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am sending an `article->tags` array of objects to my Vue component like so:

```html
<article-form
    :edit-data-tags="{{ $article->tags }}"
></article-form>
```

I get this array:

```js
[  0: { id:'1', name:'mytag' } ... ]
```

Now in my component, I want to get to the **name** field so I can store it and pass it onwards.  How can i do this?

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976830/accessing-array-object-property-in-vue-js) has the same problem, but when i try this  solution:

```js
created: function () {
   for (let tag in this.editDataTags) {
      console.log(tag.name)
   }
}
```

I get an undefined.

Comment: you said *I get this array:*, where do you get that?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim well $article->tags retrieves all tags related to said article from my tables. the Tags method is :  -> return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withTimestamps(); <- In article model

Comment: Try to print that data inside a watcher property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops are for objects, but you have an array.  Try a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
for (let tag of this.editDataTags) {
   console.log(tag.name)
}
```

or `forEach`:

```js
this.editDataTags.forEach(tag => {
   console.log(tag.name);
});
```

or `for` loop:

```js
for (let i=0; i < this.editDataTags.length; i++) {
   console.log(this.editDataTags[i].name)
}
```